# Python application with input text file to be deployed on kubernetes from bitbucket and unzip the package

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes

Im a java developer but working on python for the first time

I have a python app which takes inputs from a text file input.txt.

both the program and input file will be in bitbucket.

How do we get this bitbucket repo to the kubernetes POD and access the python package from bitbucket directly and unzip it in the pod and run the application.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options you can use listing all here

1. Add a file while creating the Docker image

   Add clone step in docker build or copy-paste if possible

> RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:User/repo.git

2. Write the sidecar **init container** which will mount your both files to file system before the main container starts

You can perform all changes before the main container should star, so **init** first downloads the data after that can unzip it or copy-paste it as per the requirement to the filesystem and that same file system will be further used by the main container and it starts running as per config.

**Ref** :

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx
      name: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: www-data
      initContainers:
      - name: git-cloner
        image: alpine/git #Change image as per need and do all process here unzip,copy or anything you can set to file system and after this main container should start
        args:
            - clone
            - --single-branch
            - --
            - https://github.com/example 
            - /data
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: www-data
      volumes:
      - name: www-data
        emptyDir: {}
```

3. You can also write you custom code and download files and set those into file system of POD however init container would be easy and good solution.

Comment: thank you for your answer Harsh Manvar.  But when we use inti car -  Will it kill itself just before the actual POD starts? And with Sidecar container, we might have memory issues as there is a limit in using the memory. So sidecar is also a pod runs alongside the main pods? Does side car also use the memory?

Comment: yes sidecar take the memory however init container would come and go once complete with work. So it Won’t be too much big footprint. If you use alpine small image in init container it will work. And it change it status to complete once done with work and majn container will start.

Comment: Sure, I will try to use sidecar container. But if they say we do not have enough memory for that. Is there any alternative to this. Like writing custom code in the pod itself and extracting the files, and unzipping the python package. Do you have any custom code example/samples.

Comment: you can check the above example shared it's not side car it's init container. first it will start download and do job for as per your code and main container will get files. you might just need to change few lines in above example